# IndexedDB getAllKeys() polyfill or similar for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, indexeddb

Is there a [getAllKeys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAllKeys) polyfill available for IE?

Or, alternatively, what is a good and **performant** implementation that works in IE (I just started using IndexedDB), since IE does not support that function?

I just need *all* primary keys in the object store - without values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added it to v1.3.0 of [indexeddb-getall-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/indexeddb-getall-shim), which previously had only supported getAll but now supports getAllKeys too. It probably isn't quite as fast as a native implementation because it needs an event to be fired for every record instead of just one for all of them, but that's unavoidable in IE and in practice I doubt you'll notice the difference.